# XSLT stylesheet drops children instead of renaming them

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I have some pretty gnarly XML that was exported from Filemaker.  There is a great post that *almost* answers my question ([XSLT question. How to pair field tags with data when original XML has them in separate sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121171/xslt-question-how-to-pair-field-tags-with-data-when-original-xml-has-them-in-se)).  The xslt stylesheet from that post elegantly renames the ugly original xml with the names keyed in the `<meta>` field.

That's great, except if you look below you will see that each row has multiple elements that should be named `batchID`, `batchPartnerID` and `batchPartnerName`.  **However, only the first child of these three elements is renamed - the rest are simply dropped.**

I imagine the stylesheet just isn't looping through the elements (the xml it was originally working on only had one child per `<COL>`. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with XSLT to fix this...  Little help?  Thanks.

**Original XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
  <PRODUCT BUILD="11-13-2014" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="Pro 13.0v4"/>
  <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="ArticleIndex.fmp12" RECORDS="3678" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a"/>
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="id" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="author" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="url" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="brand" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="publishDate" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="categoryAll" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="originalTitle" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="originalBody" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardTitle" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardSubtitle" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardPublishDate" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardBody" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardNotes" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardLastUpdated" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="standardLastReviewed" TYPE="DATE"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="batchID" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="batchPartnerID" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="batchPartnerName" TYPE="TEXT"/>
  </METADATA>
  <RESULTSET FOUND="12">
    <ROW MODID="24" RECORDID="2028">
      <COL>
        <DATA>11023</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>Tom Myer</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>http://www.sitepoint.com/really-good-introduction-xml/</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>SitePoint</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>August 2005</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA/>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>A Really Good Introduction to XML</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>A Really Good Introduction to XML —E. Berliet, Lyon, France

In this chapter, we’ll cover the basics of XML – essentially, most of the information you’ll need to know to get a handle on this exciting technology. After we’re done exploring some terminology and examples, we’ll jump right in and start working with XML documents. Then, we’ll spend some time starting the project we’ll develop through the course of this book: building an XML-powered content management system.

This excerpt is taken from No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP, SitePoint’s new release, by Thomas Myer, which was designed to help you start using XML to build intelligent ‘Future-Proof’ PHP applications today.</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>A Really, Really, Really Good Introduction to XML</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>Starting out right</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>8/24/2005</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>A Really, Really, Really Good Introduction to XML —E. Berliet, Lyon, France

In this chapter, we’ll cover the basics of XML – essentially, most of the information you’ll need to know to get a handle on this exciting technology. After we’re done exploring some terminology and examples, we’ll jump right in and start working with XML documents. Then, we’ll spend some time starting the project we’ll develop through the course of this book: building an XML-powered content management system.

This excerpt is taken from No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP, SitePoint’s new release, by Thomas Myer, which was designed to help you start using XML to build intelligent ‘Future-Proof’ PHP applications today.

The title contains over 350 pages of XML and PHP goodies. It walks you through the process of building a fully-functional XML-based content management system with PHP. And all the code used in the book is available to customers in a downloadalbe archive.

To find out more about “No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP”, visit the book’s information page, or review the contents of the entire publication. As always, you can download this excerpt as a PDF if you prefer.
     </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA/>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA/>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA/>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>4127</DATA>
        <DATA>4130</DATA>
        <DATA>4136</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>1101</DATA>
        <DATA>1107</DATA>
        <DATA>1140</DATA>
      </COL>
      <COL>
        <DATA>First Client Name</DATA>
        <DATA>Second Client Name</DATA>
        <DATA>Third Client Name</DATA>
      </COL>
    </ROW>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- the key indexes the METADATA fields by their position -->
  <xsl:key 
    name="kMetaData" 
    match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" 
    use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1" 
  />

  <!-- separate templates increase readability -->
  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <content>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" />
    </content>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
    <contentitem>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL" />
    </contentitem>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
    <!-- column name lookup is high-speed because of the key -->
    <xsl:element name="{string(key('kMetaData', position())/@NAME)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Translated XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
  <contentitem>
    <id>11023</id>
    <author>Tom Myer</author>
    <url>http://www.sitepoint.com/really-good-introduction-xml/</url>
    <brand>SitePoint</brand>
    <publishDate>August 2005</publishDate>
    <categoryAll/>
    <originalTitle>A Really Good Introduction to XML</originalTitle>
    <originalBody>A Really Good Introduction to XML —E. Berliet, Lyon, France

In this chapter, we’ll cover the basics of XML – essentially, most of the information you’ll need to know to get a handle on this exciting technology. After we’re done exploring some terminology and examples, we’ll jump right in and start working with XML documents. Then, we’ll spend some time starting the project we’ll develop through the course of this book: building an XML-powered content management system.

This excerpt is taken from No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP, SitePoint’s new release, by Thomas Myer, which was designed to help you start using XML to build intelligent ‘Future-Proof’ PHP applications today.</originalBody>
    <standardTitle>A Really, Really, Really Good Introduction to XML</standardTitle>
    <standardSubtitle>Starting out right</standardSubtitle>
    <standardPublishDate>8/24/2005</standardPublishDate>
    <standardBody>A Really, Really, Really Good Introduction to XML —E. Berliet, Lyon, France

In this chapter, we’ll cover the basics of XML – essentially, most of the information you’ll need to know to get a handle on this exciting technology. After we’re done exploring some terminology and examples, we’ll jump right in and start working with XML documents. Then, we’ll spend some time starting the project we’ll develop through the course of this book: building an XML-powered content management system.

This excerpt is taken from No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP, SitePoint’s new release, by Thomas Myer, which was designed to help you start using XML to build intelligent ‘Future-Proof’ PHP applications today.

The title contains over 350 pages of XML and PHP goodies. It walks you through the process of building a fully-functional XML-based content management system with PHP. And all the code used in the book is available to customers in a downloadalbe archive.

To find out more about “No Nonsense XML Web Development with PHP”, visit the book’s information page, or review the contents of the entire publication. As always, you can download this excerpt as a PDF if you prefer.</standardBody>
    <standardNotes/>
    <standardLastUpdated/>
    <standardLastReviewed/>
    <batchID>4127</batchID>
    <batchPartnerID>1101</batchPartnerID>
    <batchPartnerName>First Client Name</batchPartnerName>
  </contentitem>
</content>
```

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us what the expected result is and how that differs from what you're getting. You've said something vague about matching up elements in different sections and thrown a few hundred lines of XML at us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="kMetaData" match="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" use="count(preceding-sibling::fmp:FIELD) + 1" />

<!-- separate templates are not required for something as simple as this -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <content>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
            <contentitem>
                <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL">
                    <xsl:variable name="field-name" select="key('kMetaData', position())/@NAME" />
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:DATA">
                        <xsl:element name="{$field-name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="." />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </contentitem>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </content>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this is assuming that your field names are (and always will be) also valid XML element names. If you cannot be sure of that, then switch to FMPDSORESULT grammar when exporting. This will convert your field names to valid XML names (e.g. replace spaces with underscores) - but you will also need a different XSLT stylesheet.

---

### Edit:

As an example, given the following FMPDSORESULT export as the input:

**XML**

```
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>example.fmp12</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT/>
<ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1">
<some_field>Alpha</some_field>
<another_field>
<DATA>101</DATA>
<DATA>102</DATA>
<DATA>103</DATA>
</another_field>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="2" RECORDID="2">
<some_field>Bravo</some_field>
<another_field>
<DATA>21</DATA>
<DATA>22</DATA>
</another_field>
</ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'       
xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPDSORESULT/fmp:ROW">
            <row> 
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fmp:ROW/*[not(fmp:DATA)]">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fmp:DATA">
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <some_field>Alpha</some_field>
    <another_field>101</another_field>
    <another_field>102</another_field>
    <another_field>103</another_field>
  </row>
  <row>
    <some_field>Bravo</some_field>
    <another_field>21</another_field>
    <another_field>22</another_field>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Oooh, great point on the field names.  I didn't realize that FMPDSORESULT would normalize the field names, so I had been replacing mine by hand in the xml export.  Do you know of a sample stylesheet that could be used with an FMPDSORESULT that I can experiment with?

Comment: I don't see how collapsing everything into a clump of `for-each`es is an improvement over the original. Even if you don't _need_ templates, they are idiomatic of XSLT and help to keep the XSLT organized.

Comment: @JLRishe Some other time, perhaps.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - awesome, thanks for that second edit

Answer (score 0):

So it *sounds* like you want three `batchID`s with three `<DATA>` values, and the same for `batchPartnerID` and `batchPartnerName`. Is that right?

If so, you can use a `for-each` to iterate over the `<DATA>`s:

```
<xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
  <xsl:variable name="elName"
                select="key('kMetaData', position())/@NAME" />
  <xsl:for-each select="fmp:DATA">
    <xsl:element name="{$elName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

or you can use a parameterized template:

```
<xsl:template match="fmp:COL">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:DATA">
    <xsl:with-param name="elName" select="key('kMetaData', position())/@NAME" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="fmp:DATA">
  <xsl:param name="elName" select="name()" />

  <xsl:element name="{$elName}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```