# Dropping the 2 right most positions from an amount field

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to drop the cent from an amount field, the cents have an assumed decimal point. An example is 42500 this is actually $425.00.   How do I drop the last 2 positions in XSLT.   Sorry, I am very new to the XSLT language.    Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only (so far) numeric solution, which works both in XPath 1.0 (XSLT 1.0)  and XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
replace(string($in), '^0*', '')
```

Should output 425

This was discussed before on this thread too:
[Formatting numbers, excluding trailing zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457763/xsl-formatting-numbers-excluding-trailing-zeroes)

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` method, e.g.:

```
substring('42500', 1, string-length('42500') - 2)
```

Will return `425`

Answer (score 0):

**Use** (both in XPath 2.0 and in XPath 1.0):

```
floor($x div 100)
```

**where the variable `$x` contains the value** -- or you could substitute this with any wanted integer literal.

**In XPath 2.0 use**:

```
$x idiv 100
```